# Algolia facet filter by empty/null value

Tags: facet, algolia

Is there a way to filter hits by a property's value that is either null or an empty string?

*i.e., show me all objects that do not have an author*

facetFilters=author:null

facetFilters=author:''

Or include it in a list of OR values?

*i.e., show me all objects with author set to Twain or that do not have an author*

facetFilters=(author:Twain,author:null)

facetFilters=(author:Twain,author:'')

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately - as of today - Algolia doesn't support that. One work-around could be to push an extra value if it's null, like pushing `author: 'unknown'` that you could use to filter on.

Answer (score 1):

Or, you could add a [`_tags`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/managing-results/refine-results/filtering/#tags) value at index-time that you can use to filter later on:

```js
const tags: string[] = [];
if (!obj.author) tags.push('no-author');
idx.saveObject({ ...obj, _tags: tags });
```

Then, you can filter by the tag later on like so:

```js
const res = idx.search('', { filters: '_tags:no-author' });
```